# How do I load only images on scroll with javascript/jquery, all other info is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so I have about three hundred images plus associated info that load with my page, so imagine a holder block like this three hundred times:

```
<div class="contain-block">
    <a class="clickable" href="#" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['image_url'];?>" alt="<?php echo $row['name'];?>">
        <span><?php echo $name;?> </span>
        <span class="rate-holder">
            <span class="rating_<?php echo $row['average'];?>"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Waiting for all three hundred images to load is time consuming. I have a nice counter that displays the number as they load, but it still takes too long. So I want to go the route of loading the images as the user scrolls down.

I know I could do a new ajax call each time someone scrolls down, but I have a lot of filters available and I don't want to have to keep track of what record I am on or anything else.

So my question is, can I gather my entire result set as I normally do, but only load say the first nine images - the supporting info for all records can load, that's fine. Then as the user scrolls down, the remaining images are loaded.

Problems:

How do I "stop" or "prevent" the remaining images from loading once my initial nine are loaded?

Ideas:

```
$img.one('load',function() {
    //somehow disable loading when count is appropriate
    imgCount++;
});
```

and then for my scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        //recognize next set of nine records without a loaded image and load the image!!

    }
});
```

I need some help with the internal workings.

EDIT: I am looking to accomplish without a plugin if possible, but will consider if it is truly the best method.

Comment: [There is a plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) and many more you can find on web.

Comment: I've been using that plugin, it's nice and easy.

Comment: I'm using this plugin too, on my blog.

Comment: Okay that looks pretty nice...still interested in non plugin answers too.

Comment: You can load the initial nine in your HTML, then on scroll, load the rest through AJAX but keep them in a hidden div and display however many you want on scroll.